# Downloading zip file with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

When I access this url through browser it will ask me to download the file

https://some-domain.com/api/v1/file/log123.tar.gz?type=log

And I need to download this from angularjs http request

I written a factory for this, but its not downloading

Request getting 200 status but still showing loader in firebug

```
app.factory('File', ['$http','GENERAL_CONFIG', function($http, GENERAL_CONFIG) {
    var API_URL = GENERAL_CONFIG.BASE_API_URL;

    API_URL = API_URL + 'filetransfer/';

    return {
        download: function(filename, type,successcallback, errorcallback){
            var apiurl = API_URL + filename + '?type='+type
            $http.get(apiurl,{
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-download;"
                }
            }).success(successcallback).error(errorcallback);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I'd bet that nobody cares about your `Content-Type`. The browser cares about it *before* i hands it over to angularjs. It's too late and angularjs itself doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I will respond incase of current needs.

Your http request should have an additional header. 
**Set responseType: "arraybuffer".**

Then you can transform that response into a blob obj. and pass it to the callback as such: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));